# How to make a circular queue completely thread safe

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety, synchronized, java-threads

At the minute I have just added synchronized to the majority of methods as it appears that without it, these methods with not be thread safe. Is there anything else that I need to implement to ensure that it is thread safe.

Also, is there a better way to go about this. At the minute only one thread will be able to use circular queue at one time, this seems a little inefficient.

```
class CircularQueue<T> implements Iterable<T>{
  private T queue[];
  private int head, tail, size;
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public CircularQueue(){
     queue = (T[])new Object[20];
     head = 0; tail = 0; size = 0;
  }
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public CircularQueue(int n){ //assume n >=0
     queue = (T[])new Object[n];
     size = 0; head = 0; tail = 0;
  }
  public synchronized boolean join(T x){
    if(size < queue.length){
        queue[tail] = x;
        tail = (tail+1)%queue.length;
        size++;
        return true;
     }
     else return false; 
  }
  public synchronized T top(){
    if(size > 0)
        return queue[head];
    else
        return null;
  }
  public synchronized boolean leave(){
    if(size == 0) return false;
    else{
        head = (head+1)%queue.length;
        size--;
        return true;
    }
  }
  public synchronized boolean full(){return (size == queue.length);}
  public boolean empty(){return (size == 0);}

  public Iterator<T> iterator(){
      return new QIterator<T>(queue, head, size);
  }
  private static class QIterator<T> implements Iterator<T>{
      private T[] d; private int index; 
    private int size; private int returned = 0;
      QIterator(T[] dd, int head, int s){
          d = dd; index = head; size = s;
      }
    public synchronized boolean hasNext(){ return returned < size;}
    public synchronized T next(){
        if(returned == size) throw new NoSuchElementException();
        T item = (T)d[index];
        index = (index+1) % d.length;
        returned++;
        return item;
    }
    public void remove(){}
  }
}
```

Any advice or help that you can give would be appreciated!

Comment: If you want the full benefit of multithreaded you may like to consider going [lock free](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/12691/o1-lock-free-container).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to missing making your `empty()` method synchronized, your iterator is not sufficiently insulated from the host queue.  The problem is not that its methods are synchronized on iterator instances, although it's true that they are.  Your iterator is making copies of the host queue's data, so as to iterate over a snapshot of the queue.  That's a fine idea, and in that case synchronizing on the iterator itself is the right thing to do.

But you don't implement it fully.  Specifically, it is not sufficient for the constructor to execute `d = dd;`.  Arrays are objects, so that just sets the iterator's array reference to refer to the same array object that the host queue uses.  Instead, you need to make a copy of that array.  There are several ways to do so, but I would prefer to invoke the array's `clone()` method -- short and sweet.

Even then, there are thread safety issues that synchronization of your classes' methods alone cannot defend against.  Some of these involve consistency of the object over multiple method invocations.  For example, suppose one thread enqueues an object on an instance of your queue.  If that queue is shared among threads, then the one that enqueued the object cannot safely assume that it can dequeue an object later, or if it does dequeue one, that it will be the same one that it enqueued.  If it wants to be able to make such assumptions then it must either provide more broadly scoped protection or ensure that the queue instance it uses is not shared.

Other issues revolve around mutation of the enqueued objects, if indeed they are mutable.  Their state is not protected by synchronization of the queue and its iterator.

Comment: thank you so much for the detailed answer, you have given me a lot to think about

Answer (score 0):

empty() is not synchronized, the synchronized on the methods of the iterator protect the iterator (which is probably useless), but not the queue itself.

Comment: To protect the queue from the iterator would it be acceptable to clone the queue and then make the iterator based of the immutable clone?

Comment: @user3704648 sure, it would do the trick; it could be overkill though.

Comment: what would you advise instead?

Comment: @user3704648 actually, it may be the best solution